# convert invalid date to a valid date like value using R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr, lubridate

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
d1 <- c('21/01/2052 9:02','12/30/2042 9:25','10134-5-28 0:0:0','10109-12-27 0:0:0','10176-6-7 0:0:0')
d2 <- c('22/03/2052 9:22','31/10/2043 9:25','10134-6-02 0:0:0','10109-12-30 0:0:0','10176-6-9 0:0:0')
df_test <- c(d1,d2)
```

**Input**

[image]

I tried something like below using `lubridate` package but doesn't seem to help

```
mdy_hm(df_test$d1)
```

**This resulted in a warning message and resulted in `NAs` for invalid values**

It's fine if invalid dates can't be processed and returns `NA`. if I can get output as shown below for valid dates, that is also okay

I expect my output to be like shown below (for invalid dates). If invalid dates can't be processed, then just replacing them with `NA` is also fine

[image]

Can you help with this?

Comment: How is `10134-5-28 0:0:0` a valid date?

Comment: Yes, it not a valid date. Hence I have mentioned as invalid date.

Comment: If it's invalid why do you want to keep it in the data? Why not turn them to `NA`'s ? How will it be useful ahead?

Comment: We have masked the original dates by some random dates. So it's essential that we retain these. btw, I updated the sample data. valid dates can also be of `mdy_dm` or `dmy_dm` format

Comment: My aim is to read the dates in whichever format it is and produce the output as I have given.

Comment: The maximum year that can be read in R is `9999`. Anything beyond that is NA

Comment: As these values are in char format, can't we preprocess this anyway to be in same format>

Comment: @RonakShah - Or is it possible to standrdize `mdy_hm` and `dmy_hm` into `mdy_hm` in my output. It's fine if we have `NA` for invalid dates

Comment: I get an error message like this `Error in fix_replacement(replacement) : 
  argument "replacement" is missing, with no default`

Comment: you do not need to preprocess. If the year was valid, you could have used  `lubridate::parse_date_time()` function giving it the orders we expect it to have and it will parse the dates accordingly