# How to transform invalid date to valid date using Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'d1' :['2/26/2019 03:31','10241-2-19 0:0:0','31/03/2016 16:00'], 
                   'd2' :['2/29/2019 05:21','10241-2-29 0:0:0','03/04/2016 12:00']})
```

[image]

As you can see there are some invalid date values. Meaning records with year like `10241`.

On the other hand, valid dates can be in both format as `mdy_dm` or `dmy_dm`.

When I try the below, I get an error message that "date of out of range"

```
df['d1'] = pd.to_datetime(df.d1)
df['d1'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y hh:ss')
```

Is there anyway to fix this?

I expect my output to be like as shown below

[image]

Comment: hmmm, `10241` is not valid year, so cannot procesing like datetimes

Comment: Yes, so any other way is there?

Comment: If not, it's okay if you can standardize the valid dates to expected output

Comment: You asked the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60202631/convert-invalid-date-to-a-valid-date-like-value-using-r). I did tell you that the year range is up to `9999`. We can not go beyond that

Comment: Are always problematic years in format `YYYY-M-D HH:MM` ?

Comment: @Onyambu - in pandas not, [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timestamp-limitations)

Comment: @jezrael pandas uses the `datetime` module. And the maximum year for the datetime module is 9999. We cannot go beyond that. Eg try `pd.datetime(10000,10,10)` and then try `pd.datetime(9999,10,10)`

Comment: @jezrael - yes, it's in `YYYYY-M-D HH:MM` format. pLEASE NOTE 5 Y's

Comment: @Onyambu - Yop, agree, I want only say in pandas tiimestamp is not possible 9999, but less

Comment: Is possible replace `10241` to maximal full valid datetime year in pandas like `2261` ?

Comment: No, I have dates in my dataset which has values like `2261`.

Comment: Guys, can you help me with this post please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61170220/replace-value-with-a-condition-from-2-columns-using-pandas